# What return type do I mention in IEnumerable<T> in try catch block?

Tags: c#

Here I'm getting confused about what return type I need to use:

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee123()
{
    try
    {
         var x = from n in db.Employees select n;
         return x;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
         Business_Dll.Model.Errorhandlecls
            .ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i cant read minds, please take some time to format your code and specify your problem as best you can

Comment: Probably `IQuerable<Employee>`

Comment: @Saruman here if try block not their then return x is Enoughf but i'm confussing in try catch block

Comment: If i understand your question you are wondering what to return from your catch block? I'd probably `throw` the exception to the calling method. You could return `null` but then you would need to know that `null` means there was an error.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov  Iquerable<Employee> also req return type

Comment: return null and put a null check in calling method.

Comment: @AnkitKumar   thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally avoid returning nulls from methods and prefer using [Enumerable.Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042(v=vs.110).aspx). This way you can avoid null checks and safely use this method in chain with other methods (LINQ for example).

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployee123()
{
    try
    {
         var x = from n in db.Employees select n;
         return x;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
         Business_Dll.Model.Errorhandlecls
            .ExceptionLogging.SendErrorToText(ex);

         return Enumerable.Empty<Employee>();
    }
}
```